# Unable to create a new Label on a Windows Forms Application when clicking a button (C#)

Tags: c#, label

I am trying to add a new label when clicking on a button. Shouldn't be too difficult but I just can't get it working :(

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label Label10 = new Label();
        Label10.Location = new Point(23, 100);
        Label10.Text = textBox1.Text;
        Parent.Controls.Add(Label10);
    }
```

I get an error when trying to debug it with a not too explicit message:

"NullReferenceException was unhandled."

Not sure to what it may be referring... I am using the "new" keyword to create the new instance, what may I be missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to set breakpoints while debugging in Visual Studio? If so, set a breakpoint on the first statement of your button event handler and start stepping through to see what line it's actually failing on. A NullReferenceException is thrown when you're working with uninstantiated objects. In your case it's likely that "Parent" is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `Parent` `null`? It could be on there too. You might just call `this.Controls.Add(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

`textbox1` is probably what's throwing that exception.  Can you step through your code in the debugger?

Comment: Just commented that line and it is still failing :(

Comment: by the way, I can go through the code but I am not sure what I might be looking for... the detail of the exception is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" but I am not sure why... the Label is created with the new keyword, why shouldn't it be handling it as a new instance of the object? Little bit lost here...